# How to specify Jenkinsfile input values when calling pipeline job from another job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job with this definition:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('work') {
            input {
                message 'message'
                parameters {
                    text(
                        name: 'values',
                    )
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    env.values = values
                }
                sh """#!/bin/bash -xe
                    echo $values
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I trigger this job from a different job while passing a fixed value for the `values` input parameter?

Comment: [`input`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input) is for *user* input and approvement. Is it more like build [`parameters`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) you are looking for?

Comment: I think you're right, I should use `parameters` instead of `input`.